# Documentation about creating and building an enterprise wiki inside a Collaboration site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I cannot find enough documentation on the web that describe advance features when building enterprise wiki, these topics include:-

1. How to implement a workflow so that a wiki goes through an approval workflow before being published.
2. Managing the user permission on which group of user can create, edit or delete wiki pages under certain category?
3. Restrict adding wiki categories to certain users only?

Thanks in advance for any help.

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are finding content on the web because these are not the standard use cases for these features.  Wikis are collaborative in nature, and made to able a bit open, though it may only be open to contributors of a given audience.

If you are looking for publishing capabilities, then you should look at the publishing features and identify an appropriate page layout.

With regards to permissions, weather it is a wiki or a publishing site, you can configure them as individual sites and then set the appropriate permissions on the site as there is no clean way to secure an individual category.  Any page can be tagged with any category in the enterprise wiki.

Update:
An alternative suggestion would be to setup to receive change notifications so that they can perform as a librarian to ensure that things are filed in the right spot and that inappropriate content is not displayed.

Comment: so you mean there is no way to have an approval stage before publishing a wiki?

Comment: I'm not saying it cannot be done, but I'm saying that it is far enough away from the normal use case that it is unlikely somebody would have blogged about it.  I can say that dozens of projects I've done that included wikis, nobody has ever asked for workflow/publishing/approval like this.